# How do I determine the element that fires Ajax request for all modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, zepto

I'm trying to get the element that fires the ajax request. This is what I get form zepto document

> By default, Ajax events are fired on the document object. However, if
>   the context of a request is a DOM node, the events are fired on that
>   node and will bubble up the DOM

what I get from this is that ajax request is fired from document object most likely it's `<html>`

I have this piece of code and I would like to determine the source of the document

```
$(document)
.on('ajaxBeforeSend', function(e, xhr, options) {
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(e.srcElement.activeElement);
    $(e.target).closest('.ajaxContainer').addClass('pre-loader');
    // show your loader
})
.on('ajaxComplete', function(e, xhr, options) {
    $(e.target).closest('.ajaxContainer').removeClass('pre-loader');
    // hide your loader
});


<div class="ajaxContainer">
    <input id="submitBnt" type="button" value="click to fire ajax" />
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to add pre-loader class to the document that fired the ajax request, but `e.target` is always `document` object. However, I found that in Chrome `e.srcElement.activeElement` is giving me the right document where the same piece of code in Safari (iOS) is giving me the `document` object

How do I get the source element, in this case it should be `#submitBnt`, that fire ajax request for at least modern Chrome and Safari as I'm just doing mobile app.

Comment: Your code is relying on a lot of global state. If you have two forms that both do an ajax submit how are you going to decide which form the result belongs to? Using `e.target` for this seems gimmicky at best. JavaScript has excellent support for scoping. Use it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to achieve rather than having to put .pre-loader class before firing ajax and removing the class in the complete callback. I wanted to do that for all ajax requests. So, I can just put a class .ajaxContainer where I want pre-loader.

Comment: zepto mentions that it depends on the context passed to the ajax request. So, why not pass a context into the ajax request? By doing so e.target will reference said context.